# Action Event for Photo Album cancel button in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem, cancel-button

I'm working with tabBarBased application.At the time of clicking the one of the tabBarButton it opens the photo album .In photo album there is a cancel button on top(navBar) right??Here i want to perform action event for cancel button click...while click on the cancel button i want to go to the another tabBar view...

Please help me out to do this...

Thank You in advance for your consideration and effort...
Regards,
Renuga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the class definition for UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

```
@protocol UIImagePickerControllerDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
// The picker does not dismiss itself; the client dismisses it in these callbacks.
// The delegate will receive one or the other, but not both, depending whether the user
// confirms or cancels.
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_NA,__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_2_0,__IPHONE_3_0);
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;

@end
```

I think one of the methods mentioned above is what you need:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

Comment: Exactly i want this method.- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker; At the time of clicking the cancel button in photo album imagePickerControllerDidCancel method is called..inside this method i have given this 2 lines of code to navigate to another view(picture)...Pictures *picturesController = [[Pictures alloc] initWithNibName:@"Pictures" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:picturesController animated:YES];
Here control goes to picture viewWillAppear method but it wont display anything..

Comment: but,picture viewWillAppear method having 3 buttons....please help me what should i give inside imagePickerControllerDidCancel...   Thanks in advance...

Comment: please give me some ideas...what should i give inside the imagePickerControllerDidCancel method to go to the another tabBar view...

Comment: @Renuga: I am not able to tell what is actually wrong with your codes. But as a good practice I would suggest that you only use the *DidCancel* method as a way to inform your picker's delegate that your picker was just cancelled. As for those initializing and pushing stuff, you should left them to the delegate's methods, not your picker's.

Answer (score 0):

set the selectedViewController property of UITabBarController to the view controller you want to switch to. Assigning a new view controller to this property changes the currently displayed view and also selects the appropriate tab in the tab bar.